# Open/Save as dialog box

Tags: jquery

Jquery:

Is there a way to catch the event that is fired when the browser opens the Open/ Save as dialog box?
[Open/Save dialog example http://qpack.orcanos.com/helpcenter/Images/openSave.png](http://qpack.orcanos.com/helpcenter/Images/openSave.png)

I need to do something when the dialog is shown.

Comment: even if there is, don't rely on this as not all browsers open a dialog (chrome for one.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible. The browser handles this specifically so that web hackers can't force you to download a virus, which would be much easier for them if it happened in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

A i know there is no particular way to detect when this window appears. Try to add click handler on the download button/icon. Or as i solved this on my project - i added async logic. when document was generated, i passed 'succes' to client, and then JS code made some logic i needed.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I am aware.

I'm guessing that this will be opened when you click some item on the page. You best bet is to capture that event.

Given your anchor:

```
<a id="MyLink" href="MyDoc.doc">
```

A simple click handkler will intercept this event, before the above box pops up

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#MyLink").click(function() {
        alert($(this).length);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Is it always the same file type that you are checking for? If so, you could do something like

```
$("a").click(function(e){
   var extension = $(this).attr("href").substr($(this).attr("src").lastIndexOf("."));
   if ((extension && /^(zip|vbd)$/.test(extension))){
      alert("Hi now you can do whatever you needed to do!");
   }
});
```

Note no e.preventDefault(), since you still want the prompt to come up I am presuming?

[File extension check snippet](http://snipplr.com/view/16123/jquery-check-file-extension/)

Comment: It' always the same file extension (a pdf file) but the file is dinamically generated, and the href is initialized with the serverside controller that creates the file.

I found a work around since ie6 gots a strange behaviour with the jQuery submit() function.
If the function where is called the $("myForm").submit() runs and completes its execution the submit is aborted by the browser.

Asap I will post a test case on jQuery forum.

Thanks a lot 
Max

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out OpenSave:

http://www.gieson.com/Library/projects/utilities/opensave/

It's not really part of jQuery, but you can probably integrate it easily. Looks like they're using Flash to overcome the problem.